# Compile-time expression factoring for user-defined types

Tags: c++, optimization

For trivial types, compilers can optimize arithmetic expressions into a new expression, with the same result, that requires less instructions in order to compute it. For example, if `a, b` are `int`, then the expression `int c = a * a + b * a` would be computed as `(a + b) * a`, which saves an instruction.

Is there a way to tell the compiler to perform this optimization for custom types? E.g., if `A, B` are matrices, then computing `A*A + A*B` would be factored as `A*(A+B)` (at compile time), which saves about n<sup>2</sup> operations during runtime.

Comment: No there isn't, unfortunately, C++ does not work this way. There's an outside chance that if the definition of all the overloaded operators are visible to the compiler then it may effect an optimization, like that, but there is no general way to instruct the compiler to effect this optimization.

Comment: You could make an expression template library that would know how to do this, but it isn't trivial.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Those were exactly my thoughts! Was just wondering if someone could save me some headache :-)

Comment: If `A` and `B` are of custom type then it is not possible for the compiler to figure out that `A*A + A*B` is `(A+B)*A`

Comment: actually not even `a * a + b * a == (a+b)*a` holds in general for `int`. If both `a` and `b` have large magnitude but opposite sign then `a * a + b*a` can overflow while `(a+b)*a` has no issue.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number granted, but with signed overflow being UB, the compiler is free to assume it cannot happen. That changes for unsigned types though.

Comment: @talbi - suggest editing as `A*A + A*B == A * (A+B)`, but matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Answer (score 0):

First note, `A*A + A*B != (A+B)*A` for matrices, not even close. It's `A*(A+B)` and that's not the same as matrix multiplication is not commutative. That said, what you're asking for, as a conceptual thing, is feasible.

This is not a complete answer, just a heads up. As @JerryJeremiah correctly wrote, you might use expression templates for this. First for your matrix class, instead of operators implementing evaluation of expressions, you return an unevaluated context: (here I show value scemantics, of course, you might implement it using references/pointers)

```
template<typename LHS, typename RHS, char op>
struct OperatorContext {
    static constexpr char operator = op;
    const LHS lhs;
    const RHS rhs;
};

// inside Matrix {
    template<typename LHS, typename RHS, char op>
    friend auto operator+(const Matrix& lhs, OperatorContext<LHS, RHS, op>& rhs) {
        return OperatorContext<Matrix, OperatorContext<LHS, RHS, op>, '+'>{lhs, rhs};
    }

    template<typename LHS, typename RHS, char op>
    friend auto operator+(OperatorContext<LHS, RHS, op>& lhs, const Matrix& rhs) {
        return OperatorContext<Matrix, OperatorContext<LHS, RHS, op>, '+'>{lhs, rhs};
    }

    friend auto operator+(const Matrix& lhs, const Matrix& rhs) {
        return OperatorContext<Matrix, Matrix, '+'>{lhs, rhs};
    }

    // similarly for other operators
// }

// furthermore, you need similar operators for 2 OperatorContext arguments
```

Then, you can implement assignment operator to `Matrix` from various `OperatorContext<>` versions. Here, you might do the optimization, as you have complete type info. Note that this only works until you assign to a variable. E.g.:

```
// inside Matrix {
    Matrix& operator=(OperatorContext<OperatorContext<Matrix, Matrix, '*'>, OperatorContext<Matrix, Matrix, '*', '+'> other) {
        if (other.lhs.lhs == other.rhs.lhs) { // preferably compare-by-address
          *this = other.lhs.lhs * (other.lhs.rhs + other.rhs.rhs)
        } else {
          *this = other.lhs.lhs * other.lhs.rhs + other.rhs.lhs * other.rhs.rhs;
        }
        return *this;
    }
// }
```